# Yocto & wpa_supplicant - installing libwpa_client.so

Tags: yocto, bitbake, wpa-supplicant

I'm working with this Yocto/ Bitbake [recipe](https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/tree/dunfell/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant) for wpa_supplicant (v2.9) which is a bbappend for this [recipe](https://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant_2.9.bb?h=dunfell). I had significant difficulties getting the associated library (libwpa_client.so) included in the install process during my Yocto/ Poky build. Eventually I created my own bbappend which contained:

```
# Force build of library libwpa_client.so
do_configure_append() {
    echo 'CONFIG_BUILD_WPA_CLIENT_SO=y' >>  wpa_supplicant/.config
}

# Avoid QA errors:
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += " ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

# Force install of libwpa_client.so
do_install_append(){
    install -d ${D}${libdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/wpa_supplicant/libwpa_client.so ${D}${libdir}
}
```

Using the config option CONFIG_BUILD_WPA_CLIENT_SO=y failed to install the library so thats why I went with the do_install_append() method. I find it hard to believe this hasn't come up before for others so I think I'm missing something, I can't find similar hacks/ patches.

Can't someone point out if I'm missing something obvious?? There's a [patch](https://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-connectivity/wpa-supplicant/wpa-supplicant/0001-build-Re-enable-options-for-libwpa_client.so-and-wpa.patch) file for v2.10 which may be associated with this issue, but I think it's more an issue with the Makefile as the library file was successfully built for v2.9, just not populated to the final image.

If this isn't a waste of half a day perhaps this will help others.

Regards,

Comment: It helps me. thanks